# How to show Admob native ads in flutter pageview horizontal direction scroll?

Tags: flutter, admob

For ListView builder there is seperator to put ads in between the list of data. How do I do the same thing for PageView. While I scroll horizontally through this PageView, I want to show a native ad in between, how do I do it? Any links to implementation will be appreciated.